# PHP generate preview link with iTunes API - SLOW

Tags: php, html, mysql, itunes

I am having problems. I am trying to generate a preview song button to preview songs stored at a MySQL database, using iTunes search API.

I have written the following code:

```
<?php

// Script de conexión a la base de datos.
include "includes/connect.php";

$songs = "";

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT artista, titulo, nombre, count(id) as uploadCount FROM canciones GROUP BY artista, titulo ORDER BY uploadCount DESC");
$query->execute(array($songs));
$songs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<table id="tblCanciones" width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
            <tr align="left">
              <th class="tblCancionesHeader" width="33%">Artista</th>
              <th class="tblCancionesHeader" width="32%">T&iacute;tulo</th>
              <th class="tblCancionesHeader" width="20%">Pedida por</th>
              <th class="tblCancionesHeader" width="10%">Veces</th>
              <th class="tblCancionesHeader" width="4%"></th>
            </tr>';

foreach($songs as $song) {

// Buscar el link de la preview de la canción en la iTunes store...
$term = urlencode($song["artista"])."+".urlencode($song["titulo"]);
$json =  file_get_contents('http://itunes.apple.com/search?term='.$term.'&limit=1&entity=musicArtist,musicTrack,album,mix,song');
$array = json_decode($json, true);

        echo '<tr align="left">
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="tblCancionesFila">'.$song["artista"].'</td>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="tblCancionesFila">'.$song["titulo"].'</td>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="tblCancionesFila">'.$song["nombre"].'</td>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="tblCancionesFila">'.$song["uploadCount"].'</td>';

                        if (!isset($array['results'][0]['previewUrl'])) {
                            echo '<td nowrap="nowrap" class="tblCancionesFila">---</td>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<td nowrap="nowrap" class="tblCancionesFila"><a href="'.$array['results'][0]['previewUrl'].'"><img src="images/imgPreview.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="preview" title="preview" border="0" /></a></td>';
                        }

        echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

It works more or less with some limitations. I just want it to fetch a preview link, so I am limiting the results to 1. So sometimes it does not find a result...

The main problem is that it is slow, very slow to fetch the results...

I guess I am doing something wrong.

Is there any other easy way of obtaining this same functionality but maybe using other service other than itunes, like spotify, soundcloud, or others?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get all games(apps) details from iTunes using php? I'm searching but i can't get answer. I'm also i used search API. But i didn't know how to use that? Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696311/get-game-details-from-itunes-using-php#_=_

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone could find this useful... I found a much wiser way of doing this!

I just changed the focus of my problem, so now, instead of generating the links inside the SQL query, which is obviously very slow and not very wise..., I generate a link each time a user sends a new song to the SQL database.

So, the user sends a song (artist, title), and just before inserting the data into the DB, I use itunes API to generate a preview link with the given artist and title of the song. Then I input artist, title and preview link into the DB.

So generating the data table with all songs, title, artist and preview link, is as easy as extracting the data from the SQL DB.

Sometimes thinking things can be pretty useful...